# How to use su command over adb shell?

Tags: android, linux, shell, android-ndk, adb

I need to make a script that executes a lots of thing on Android device, my device is rooted, when I enter on the shell, I can give the command su, and it works but I need pass this command like:

```
adb shell "
su;
mv /sdcard/Download/app_test /data/local;
cd /data/local;
./app_test;
exit;
exit;
"
```

when I put some commands before the su it works, according what I read su creates a new shell that return immediately, but I need give commands on the su shell, how can I do that?

Comment: `su -c` will invoke a command based on su's arguments.

Comment: If you need to have root access on emulators - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds/45668555#45668555.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, if your phone is rooted you can run commands with the `su -c` command.

Here is an example of a `cat` command on the `build.prop` file to get a phone's product information.

```sh
adb shell "su -c 'cat /system/build.prop |grep "product"'"
```

This invokes root permission and runs the command inside the `' '`.

Notice the 5 end quotes, that is required that you close ALL your end quotes or you will get an error.

For clarification the format is like this.

```sh
adb shell "su -c '[your command goes here]'"
```

Make sure you enter the command EXACTLY the way that you normally would when running it in shell.

Comment: For me your solution didn't work instead `adb shell "su 0 command"` works and here is one example `adb shell "su 0 chmod 644 /system/priv-app/myApp.apk"`

Comment: What if the command I need to put already had `"` ? For example I need to run this command to execute a scheduled backup of SwittBackup app (https://swiftapps.org/faq#schedulecommand) : `am start -n org.swiftapps.swiftbackup/.shortcuts.ShortcutsActivity -e "cmd" "-s vmppnc"
` . How can I pass it correctly to `adb shell "su ` ?

Answer (score 17):

On my Linux, I see an error with

```
adb shell "su -c '[your command goes here]'"
```

> su: invalid uid/gid '-c'

The **solution** is on Linux

```
adb shell su 0 '[your command goes here]'
```

Comment: Had the same issue and `su 0` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be valid for Windows too...

Answer (score 7):

The `su` command does not execute anything, it just raise your privileges.

Try `adb shell su -c YOUR_COMMAND`.

Comment: `su: invalid uid/gid '-c'`

Answer (score 4):

### 1. adb shell su

win cmd

```
C:\>adb shell id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)

C:\>adb shell 'su -c id'
/system/bin/sh: su -c id: inaccessible or not found

C:\>adb shell "su -c id"
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:magisk:s0

C:\>adb shell su -c id   
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:magisk:s0
```

win msys bash

```sh
msys2@bash:~$ adb shell 'su -c id'
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:magisk:s0
msys2@bash:~$ adb shell "su -c id"
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:magisk:s0
msys2@bash:~$ adb shell su -c id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:magisk:s0
```

### 2. adb shell -t

if want run `am` cmd, `-t` option maybe required:

```sh
C:\>adb shell su -c am stack list
cmd: Failure calling service activity: Failed transaction (2147483646)

C:\>adb shell -t su -c am stack list
Stack id=0 bounds=[0,0][1200,1920] displayId=0 userId=0
...
```

shell options:

```
 shell [-e ESCAPE] [-n] [-Tt] [-x] [COMMAND...]
     run remote shell command (interactive shell if no command given)
     -e: choose escape character, or "none"; default '~'
     -n: don't read from stdin
     -T: disable pty allocation
     -t: allocate a pty if on a tty (-tt: force pty allocation)
     -x: disable remote exit codes and stdout/stderr separation
```

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
> Version 30.0.5-6877874

Answer (score 2):

By default CM10 only allows root access from Apps not ADB. Go to Settings -> Developer options -> Root access, and change option to "Apps and ADB".

Answer (score 1):

for my use case, i wanted to grab the SHA1 hash from the magisk config file. the below worked for me.

```
adb shell "su -c "cat /sbin/.magisk/config | grep SHA | awk -F= '{ print $2 }'""
```

Answer (score 1):

I opt for the following:

```
adb shell su root <your command>
```

e.g., to access the external storage (sd card):

```
adb shell su root ls storage/0/emulated
```