# listFiles() returns null on /storage/emulated, while /storage/emulated/0 exists

Tags: java, android, file-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-storage

I am testing on android 27 emulator and trying to traverse some directories.

When I try to traverse `/storage/emulated` directory, the method `listFiles()` returns `null` while there `/storage/emulated/0` exists.

Here is a testing code:

```
File emuDir = new File("/storage/emulated");
File[] emuDirFiles = emuDir.listFiles(); // returns null.

File exStorageDir = new File("/storage/emulated/0")
exStorageDir.exists(); // returns true
```

P.S. I have added the proper storage permission in manifest and granted the runtime permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Android won't grant your app a permission to access `/storage/emulated`.

**Long answer and the reason your solution is not working:**

Which permissions you've granted? I presume they're `EXTERNAL_WRITE/EXTERNAL_READ` and those will give you access to `/storage/emulated/0` which is the same directory returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Android doesn't give read/write permission to `/storage/emulated`. As a side note, if `File.canRead()` returns `false` you can't `listFiles()` of that directory. In your case, even if you have added permissions `emuDir.canRead()` will return `false` because those permissions grants access to `/storage/emulated/0` not to `/storage/emulated`

Comment: I've granted both `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Also checked the method `canRead()` on `/storage/emulated`, it returns `false`. I'm wondering why this is happening coz I can traverse system directories for example `/proc` directory and others as well.

Comment: If it returns `false`, you can't do anything. Android's `/system` directory is readable (`canRead()` returns true) that's why you can list files in this directory. But `/storage/emulated` is not readable unless you root your device.

Comment: Unfortunately, Android doesn't have permission category to access to that directory, no matter what Permission you're adding.

Comment: May I ask the reason you're trying to access that directory, just out of curiosity. You don't have to answer if it's a private thing )). I may suggest an alternative if anything comes to my mind.

Comment: I'm traversing all directories starting from `/`, with this happening, it will fail to traverse `/storage/emulated`! Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you root your device you can use `su/sudo`. But I don't have first-hand experience with those commands. I could have helped you but I don't want to root my device. You can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/27274339/5636313 as a start point

Comment: Thank you, I think this is an accepted answer. However it's a little confusing that it is not accessible in this way.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to Scoped Storage. To solve this, write

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in application tag of manifest file like below.

[image: solution]

For More information: https://medium.com/@pednekarshashank33/android-10s-scoped-storage-image-picker-gallery-camera-d3dcca427bbf

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. Be aware though this fix will not work when targeted to Android 11+.

Answer (score 0):

After request permission successful. Add this line:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to scope "application" in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: worth to notes: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/scope-storage-myths-ca6a97d7ff37